# What are the prerequisites for understanding Lattice based Cryptography, LWE or RLWE based on SVP?

Tags: lattice-crypto, lwe, ring-lwe

I'm new to Quantum Resistant Cryptography, so, I thought of diving into Lattice based crypto, LWE and ring LWE. I realise that the hard problem involving them is the "shortest vector problem". But I don't understand why it is a hard problem, or comprehend its hardness. The only sources that I can find on the internet, speak language that only advanced mathematicians/computer scientists can understand. Currently, I only know of Lattices from Linear Algebra and also, I realise that we are working on descrete fields.
It would be kind, if someone, could show me sources, or explain how LWE, or RLWE  works, and why the problem is hard for both Quantum as well as Classical computers. I would love to build a solid foundation on the understanding of this new crypto, and I hope this post will serve as a starting point for many beginners interested in Lattice Based Cryptography.

Every help, answer, advice or comment will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=post+quantum+cryptography&crid=2ZGDZHGX7UBS1&sprefix=post+quant%2Caps%2C324&ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_10

Comment: A quick search for tutorial and lwe on eprint.iacr.org gave me [Lattice Based Cryptography for Beginners](https://ia.cr/2015/938).